# React Native search-box with componentDidUpdate

Tags: react-native

I'm having issue with my componentDidUpdate always updating the render()/state.

My state by default has applicantsData

```
this.state = {
  applicantsData: []
};
```

ComponentDidMount and ComponentDidUpdate call my method that loads data for the state

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getApplicants();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // needs to be a unique value
      if (prevProps.applicantsData !== this.props.applicantsData) {
        this.getApplicants();
      }
  }

  getApplicants = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('CurrentPropertyID')
      .then((value) => {
        const propID = JSON.parse(value);
        this.props.getApplicants(propID);
        this.setState({ applicantsData: this.props.applicantsData });
    });
  }
```

Then, I have a search box and a FlatList to create my component. I'm using `react-native-search-box'` for the search box

```
<Search
   ref="search_box"
   onSearch={this.onSearch}
   onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
/>
<FlatList
   extraData={this.state}
   data={this.state.applicantsData}
   keyExtractor={(item) => {
       return item.id.toString();
   }}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

My onChangeText method:

```
onChangeText = (searchText) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let data = this.props.applicantsData;
      if (searchText !== '') {
        data = data.filter((item) =>
          item.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()) ||
          item.Email.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()) ||
          item.Phone.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase())
        ).map(({ id, name, dtEntered, approve, Email, Phone, image }) =>
              ({ id, name, dtEntered, approve, Email, Phone, image }));
        this.setState({ applicantsData: data });
      } else {
        this.setState({ applicantsData: this.props.applicantsData });
      }
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

Everything is working fine. The data is loaded and displayed in the screen. However, the componentDidUpdate is called all the name and keep updating the props, so when I use the search box to filter my state.applicantsData, it is quickly filtered, then all the data is loaded again because the this.getApplicants was called inside the componentDidUpdate().

Does it make sense? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is the problem.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // needs to be a unique value
      if (prevProps.applicantsData !== this.props.applicantsData) {
        this.getApplicants();
      }
  }
```

You have to use deep compare method to compare applicantsData.
You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal or `isEqual` from lodash